# jQuery .prepend reversed the array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects that I grab images from and display on the page, only once displayed, the last one is showing first, and the first one is last - backwards. If I use .append() then it's in the right order but semantically I need to use .prepend() so that my html elements display correctly. Any suggestions on what's going on? I am not able to find anything online as to what's causing this. A link to the doc describing this behavior would be great too!

Here's the jQuery code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < skills.length; i++) {
    var icon = '<img id="' + items[i].id + '" class="item-img-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-index="'+ i +'"src="' + items[i].iconurl + '" />';
    $('#items-large').prepend(icon);
};
```

Comment: `.prepend()` will always insert the argument as first child of the parent. I don't understand why you have to use `.preprend()` "semantically". `.append()` seems to to exactly what you need: You want to *append* each element in the array to the parent.

Comment: Thanks. You had a good point. I re-organized my code a bit within the HTML and now it's all good. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepend isn't reversing the array. During the first loop, your first skill is added to the front of your #items-large. Which is good, because you probably want that first one to be the first icon on items-large! However, during the second loop, the second icon is added to the front (prepended) to #items-large. Ah! Now the first icon is actually the last, and the second icon is the first! This repeats for all of your icons and, in the end, your last icon in the array is in front, or first, and the first icon in the array is in back, or last.

And depending on what else is in #items-large, you may not want to use append, either.

Imagine the following:

```
<div id="items-large">
<!-- prepended icons go here -->
    <h1>My awesome icons</h1>
<!-- appended icons go here -->
</div>
```

And appending would still result in the same incorrect order of icons!

You're smart enough to figure out what to do from here, but if you need a solution:

> You could reverse your icons in the array by hand, or you could call reverse() on your array before you begin prepending them.

Comment: Figured this out, but thanks for the explanation of how items are added! It's really helpful. I need to keep learning about the context of objects!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of incrementing could you try decrementing your loop or array.reversing it if you choose to still increment the loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can "reverse" the elements in an array using the [`.reverse()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reverse.asp) method.

Then use `.append()`.

```
// Reverse the array order
items = items.reverse();

for (var i = 0; i < skills.length; i++) {
    var icon = '<img id="' + items[i].id + '" class="item-img-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-index="'+ i +'"src="' + items[i].iconurl + '" />';
    $('#items-large').append(icon);
};
```

Comment: using .reverse() method gives an error of "not a function".

Comment: Is `items` an array? Or should it be `skills` maybe?